# Primefaces editable p:selectOneMenu chrome autofill problem

Tags: javascript, primefaces, autofill, selectonemenu

I am trying to cancel chrome autofilling on my inputs using `autocomplete="off"`. I have a case of a `<p:selectOneMenu>` which have the attribute `editable=true`. Then, when I focus on the field, chrome autocomplete propose some past texts. How can I cancel this autofilling knowing that the attribute `autocomplete` is not available for `<p:selectOneMenu>`?

I have already tried to manage it through javascript, but the `onfocus` attribute concern dropdown click and not input area focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not PrimeFaces related. It is that Chrome AutoFill has been a mess over the years.

Here is the thread you want and look at how many times its been updated or answers changed just in the last 3 years.

[Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Basically Google has gone back and forth about allowing the developer to control what gets autofilled or not and for a while they completely ignore `autocomplete="off"` saying developers shouldn't decide what a user wants.  Then they added some new auto-complete flags.  Its a 100% mess in my opinion.